# How can i redirect from 1 page to product detail page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

I want when i click on the anchor(a) tag means image it redirect me the product detail page what should i do for it?

Here is my code.

```
 <?php
    include 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$hint = "hp";
$sql = "SELECT p.entity_id, pv.value as name, pt.value as description, pm.value as imagesPath
                FROM catalog_product_entity as p
                INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar as pv on pv.entity_id = p.entity_id and pv.attribute_id = 71
                INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text as pt on pt.entity_id = p.entity_id and pt.attribute_id = 72
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as pm on pm.entity_id = p.entity_id and pm.attribute_id = 88
                 WHERE pv.value like '%".$hint."%'";

               foreach($readConnection->fetchAll($sql) as $orders)
                  {

                     $id1 = $orders["entity_id"];
                     $result = $orders['name'];
                     $result1 = $orders['description'];
                     $result2 = $orders['imagesPath'];

                     echo "<ul><li>$result</li>
                     <li>$result1</li> </ul>";

                    ?>
                    <a href="#?id=<?php echo $id1 ?>"><img src="media/catalog/product<?php echo $result2; ?>" width="50px" height="50px;" /></a>

                     <?php

                  }

 ?>
```

Comment: why you are using sql query?

Comment: so what should i use?

Comment: basically you want retrieve all product which contain 'hp' in their name?

Comment: yes youare right but in search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use below code

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection() 
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%hp%'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    //echo $product->getSku();
    echo "<ul><li>".$product->getName()."</li>
            <li>".$product->getDescription()."</li> </ul>";
    echo '<a href="'.Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL).'index.php/'.$product->getUrlPath().'"> <img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/'.$product->getImage().'"></a>';
}
```

Above code is tested

For product image you can use below code

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
        ->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() );
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much dear 
its working perfect 
Thank You

Comment: but it is not picking the image .

Comment: @AfzalKhan find updated answer

Comment: not working :( ..

Comment: @AfzalKhan its working at my side... well will you share output for one product

Comment: I have shared the link see that

Comment: @AfzalKhan I want what are you getting for `$product->getImage()` and `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
        ->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() );` and please try to give reply in comment only

Comment: when i go to inspect element it's showing me this 
src="http://127.0.0.1/magento/media/catalog/productno_selection"